# Drawing a circular region from bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have x and y coordinates of the top-leftmost point of square enclosing the circle and the radius. Is there a way I can draw the circular region of a bitmap corresponding to the given data? I am looking for a function parallel to canvas.drawCircle(x,y,r,Paint) but I want the bitmap object to be in the the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BitmapShader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html).

There is a nice article by Romain Guy called Android Recipe #2, [fun with shaders](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/).